# How to interpret CakePHP stack trace

Tags: apache, cakephp

Just moved an app from WAMP on a dev machine to a linux server.  Not using htaccess files and defining it in Apache instead.  The app using Cake's Auth. When finally visiting:

```
https://www.myserver.com/myapp
```

I then get this error:

```
2014-04-04 10:54:00 Error: [NotFoundException] Not Found
Request URL: /myapp/login
Stack Trace:
#0 /srv/www/cakephp-2.3.10/lib/Cake/View/View.php(945): include()
#1 /srv/www/cakephp-2.3.10/lib/Cake/View/View.php(907): View->_evaluate('/srv/www/myapp...', Array)
#2 /srv/www/cakephp-2.3.10/lib/Cake/View/View.php(471): View->_render('/srv/www/myapp...')
#3 /srv/www/cakephp-2.3.10/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(952): View->render(NULL, NULL)
#4 /srv/www/cakephp-2.3.10/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(194): Controller->render()
#5 /srv/www/cakephp-2.3.10/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#6 /srv/www/myapp/app/webroot/index.php(110): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#7 {main}
```

The error in the browser is:

```
Error: The requested address '/myapp/login' was not found on this server.
```

The Apache conf has:

```
Alias /myapp/srv/www/myapp/app/webroot

<Directory /srv/www/myapp/app/webroot>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Fix: when I change debug to 1 or 2 it works!

Comment: Propably error with routing. Try with this `Configure::write('App.base','/myapp/');` in `bootstrap.php`. Your base path should be changed.

Comment: when I change debug to 1 or 2 it works!

Comment: You said `Fix: when I change debug to 1 or 2 it works!`. Are you planning to run your application on debug mode 1 or 2?